# Where is make on msys2/mingw-w64?

Tags: gnu-make, mingw-w64

On msys2, I installed the mingw-w64 toolchain. I can run gcc from MINGW64 shell, but not make. **pacman** claims `mingw-w64-x86_64-make` is installed. What gives?

Comment: pacman -S -yy  mingw-w64-x86_64-make-4.2.1-2 reeports reinstall successful, still bash says make: command not found

Answer (score 17):

Just to add some details to the previous comments: On Windows you can open a command prompt (as admin), go to the `c:\<your msys installation path>\mingw64\bin` directory and run `mklink make mingw32-make.exe` to create a symbolic link. That will allow you to run the `make` command in the MINGW64 shell

Comment: Thank you! I saw some other post where the best suggestion was to just copy the executable and rename it, I figured there _had_ to be a better way!

Comment: This is not correct.   `make` and `mingw32-make` cannot be used interchangeably.  See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple but not obvious. They distribute mingw32-make.exe and expect you to symlink it by hand. Typical *nix-think.

Comment: No, this  is NOT the expectation!  DO NOT symlink this and expect it to work.  It does different things than the msys make (`pacman -S make`) with regard to the shell interaction and path manipulation.   90% of the time you want to use the msys make, not the mingw32-make.  Install them both if you know what you are doing and you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH directories may not be set correctly.

[This thread](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1132) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You are meant to use the make installed by `pacman -S make` for most builds, not the one installed by `pacman -S <target>-make`.

Remember that make interacts heavily with the shell, and in this platform the shell is doing many magical things to bridge the gap between sets of platform conventions.   `make` therefore also needs to be magical.   The only reason to use the -make is because it does not have dependencies on the msys libraries, or for the rare cases when you don't want the magic.

Many Makefiles will just not work with the target / non-msys versions, so probably you just want to use `pacman -S make`.

See: https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Porting/